Why don't downvotes cost reputation?
Downvotes used to cost a few reputations points (2 I think I remember), but since a while, I can downvote without any penalty.
Has that been added to our site since it's in beta or is it a bug?

This is definitely by design, and I would encourage you and the other high-rep users to think about whether an expert would really ask this question, and if not, don't be afraid to down-vote.

@TalFishman: I think it does cost rep point in StackOverflow. I'm pretty sure. As you have seen, I have been pretty active in both downvoting and closing and I'll keep doing so for the sake of the site.

Downvotes on questions are free. That's to encourage "more balanced question voting" and produce better scores for questions.
